# Add element without defining a model Option Field

Tags: python, django

I have the following form in Django to use it in a filter

```
class TeachersForm (forms.Form):
     teachers = forms.ModelChoiceField (
        required = False,
        queryset = Teachers.objects.all (),
        label = "Teacher"
     )
```

Model Teacher

```
class Docente(model.Models):
    name= model.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name= model.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Model Student

```
class Student (model.Models):
    name= model.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name= model.CharField(max_length=30)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=False, blank=False)
```

I need an option to be able to filter the students who have not assigned any teacher, but the queryset returns me the teachers objects that exist.

I need to say to show the students where assigned teacher is equal to "Unassigned".

"Unassigned" must be a filter option that for Django returns None

For example:

- Not assigned
- Pepito
- Fulano
- Sultano

Comment: Show us your related models.

Comment: Teacher and student

Comment: try this query students = Student.objects.filter(teacher=None) this will give you the students who have not assigned any teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have made the teacher foreign key as null = False

Model Student 

class Student (model.Models):
    name= model.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name= model.CharField(max_length=30)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT,)

To get the students who have not assigned any teacher by :
     student_list = Student.objects.filter(teacher__is_null = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
students = Student.objects.filter(teacher__is_null = True)
```